# PHP memory_limit несколько скриптов выполняющихся одновременно?

Tags: php, apache, веб-сервер

Что такое `memory_limit` понятно, объем максимальной выделяемой оперативной памяти на 1 скрипт (сценарий).

Но любой веб сервер может одновременно обрабатывать сразу несколько скриптов, или же они все также выполняются один за одним а не одновременно, это я и хочу узнать. Например на сервере стоит 1ГБ оперативы, что если одновременно будут выполняться допустим 10 скриптов с лимитом в 128мб, что в таком случае, не ляжет ли сервер?

Comment: если одновременно и если каждый сожрет по 100 метров то да. Но если у тебя каждый скрипт ест больше нескольких мегабайт, то надо его переписывать

Comment: что такое "мнимая асинхронность"?

Comment: По идее сервер может обрабатывать несколько запросов одновременно (асинхронно), но может быть технически это все те же последовательные синхронные процессы. Это имел в виду под  "мнимая асинхронность"

Comment: учитывая, что каждая картинка и каждый скриптик - это отдельный процесс, то при последовательной обработке ты бы ждал загрузки этой страницы 5 минут

Comment: А очередь поднять? Тот же самый кролик или редис. Он разгрузит сервер от единовременной нагрузки, ваши жрущие запросы будут стоят в очереди и выполняться своевременно, когда это нужно

Comment: Веб-сервера могут работать в нескольких режимах. Почитайте https://hostiq.ua/wiki/php-modes/ для получения более полного представления о них.